# SublimeVideo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video, hash

I've been using [SublimeVideo](http://docs.sublimevideo.net), and I've done so much with it already for the site I'm working on.

I've got 15-20 videos that I'm successfully using via SublimeVideo on a site in the basic way, by having a link on the page the user clicks on, and when clicked, the video opens in the SublimeVideo lightbox and starts playing.

But now, I'm needing to create "shorter URLs" for these videos that can be sent out in print publications and emails, and where the user is taken to the website to view, not just the video file.

Ideally, I was hoping to just use the id/data-uid with a hashtag in a single-page url and have the chosen video to automatically launch'n'play within the lightbox. That seems to be impossible (?).

I could settle with having a single page with the video tags hidden and have the hashtag unhide it and play it when in the URL. If none of this can work in a slick way, maybe I'll just go old-school and make a page for each video and just embed it in the page..

Anyway, after scouring all the documentation pages, their forums, and searching the web, I've only found a couple of options - neither of which have actually worked. I'll paste them below:

First, here's an example of the HTML I'm using for all the videos:

```
<p class=""><a href="#video1" class="sublime" data-autoresize="fit">video1 text link on page</a></p>

<video id="video1" data-uid="video1" title="video1 description" poster="/assets/images/video1.jpg" width="1084" height="574" style="display:none" data-autoresize="fit" preload="none">
    <source src="/assets/videos/video1.mp4" />
</video>
```

That, by itself, works great! I don't want to change that. When the text link is clicked, the lightbox opens and the video plays perfectly.

So, let's say the page that holds the 15-20 videos with the above code for them is at:

```
http://example.com/resources/index.php
```

I thought I could simply make that URL for the first video:

```
http://example.com/resources/index.php#video1
```

...or even better...

```
http://example.com/resources#video1
```

...and follow suit for all the other video IDs.

And to get that to work, I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    sublimevideo.ready(function() 
        {
        if (window.location.hash == '#video1') {
                             sublime('video1').play();
        } else 
        if (window.location.hash == '#video2') {
                             sublime('video2').play();
        } else 
        if (window.location.hash == '#video3') {
                             sublime('video3').play();
        }
    });     
</script>
```

...that doesn't work. For some reason it works with whatever the first video is on the page, but by "work" I mean, it unhides it and makes it playable, not open in the lightbox and auto play.

So then I found code in the sharing documentation area like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var hashtag = "#video1";
    var hashtag = "#video2";
    var hashtag = "#video3";

    if (document.location.hash == hashtag) {
      showTheVideo(hashtag);
    }

    function showTheVideo(hashtag) {
    }    
</script>
```

...but that doesn't work either.

Could somebody that does know JavaScript please spell it out for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put the code that fixed the issue for me here in hopes it helps somebody else someday that may search and find it.

By putting the below code in the head of the page, under the...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/UniqueIDprovidedInYourAccountGoesHere.js"></script>
```

...library (which is the random characters/numbers .js that SublimeVideo gives you in your account area), I was able to finally get the above detailed problem to work (YAY!!!).

So, using the same example as above, this URL now works as I needed (by not only taking you to the resources page, but also by launching the particular video in its lightbox).

```
http://example.com/resources.php#video=interview2
```

...and by putting:

```
RewriteRule ^resources$ resources.php [L]
```

...in the .htaccess file in the same dir, I was able to make it even easier for the user:

```
http://example.com/resources#video=interview2
```

As I understand it, the below JavaScript addition finds the hash, then looks for the "video=", then takes whatever is after that, and if it finds a matching "id" in an "a" tag, then it tells it to do it's SublimeVideo thing by launching that video in the lightbox. Brilliant!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var lochash    = location.hash.substr(1);
            var mylocation = lochash.substr(lochash.indexOf('video='))
                             .split('&')[0]
                             .split('=')[1];

            sublime.ready(function () {

                var lightbox = sublime.lightbox(mylocation);
                    lightbox.open();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's the HTML part (for reference):

```
<p class=""><a href="#video2" id="interview2" class="sublime" data-autoresize="fit">video2 text link on page that i left as reference for the user in case they close the video that was launched from the publication</a></p>

<video id="video2" data-uid="video2" title="video2 description" poster="/assets/images/interview2.jpg" width="1084" height="574" style="display:none" data-autoresize="fit" preload="none">
    <source src="/assets/videos/interview2.mp4" />
</video>
```

Also note: I found out through trial and error that the name of the video in the URL, after the "#video=" must be the same as the "ID" in the "A" tag, not the "video" tag! So, you'll notice that the "id=" is (and needs to be) different between the two. The "id=" in the "video" tag is instead the same as the "href=".